# Pass blank as argument to a command

Tags: macros

How can I pass a blank to this command

```
\newcommand{\iam}[1][happy]{I am #1.}
```

so that I get this result

```
I am .
```

Note: My actual command operates in the math mode, so the space between "am" and "." is of no concern.

Comment: `\iam[]`?  ........     ...

Comment: OK. It isn't much of an answer but it is all yours ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass an empty optional argument, thus overriding the non-blank default, just use `[]`:

```
\iam[]
```