# How to pass optional empty arguments in a newcommand down to another command with optional empty arguments in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I would like to define a `newcommand` with two optional arguments, which in turn, calls on another command with two optional arguments.

Something like the following (`\B` calls `\A`). How do I do it?

```latex
\newcommand{A}[3][][]{{#1 + #2 + #3}}
\newcommand{B}[3][][]{#1 + \A[#2][#3]{#1}}

\B{9}
\B[1][]{9}
\B[][3]{9}
\B[1][3]{9}
```

**EDIT**

I tried to give a similar MWE, but I am afraid that the above example actually may not properly convey exactly what I need.

The reason I had this question is to create a command that takes in a certain bib-item and highlights it. I would like to pass two optional arguments to `\parencite[pre][post]{#1}` (where `pre` and `post` could be empty) via a newcommand `\hlcite[pre][post]{#1}`. The command `\hlcite` would then highlight the references.

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,          % backend: biber
    style=authoryear,       % style: numeric-comp, authoryear
    sorting=ynt,            % sorting: none, ynt
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{soul} 
\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}}
```

```latex
%% This works
\newcommand{\hlcite}[1]{\colorbox[green]{\mbox{\parencite{#1}}}}
```

```latex
%% But this throws error
\newcommand{\hlcite}[3]{\hlc[green]{\mbox{\parencite[#2][#3]{#1}}}}
```

#### References

**Adding optional arguments**

- [How do I add optional arguments in newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567759/how-do-i-add-optional-arguments-in-newcommand)
- [Pass blank as argument to a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209044/pass-blank-as-argument-to-a-command)
- [Special behavior if optional argument is not passed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217757/special-behavior-if-optional-argument-is-not-passed)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144176/latex-newcommand-default-argument-is-empty
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812214/latex-optional-arguments
- [Optional argument for newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58628/optional-argument-for-newcommand)
- [\newcommand to create a command with optional arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192936/newcommand-to-create-a-command-with-optional-arguments)
- [Passing optional arguments to a command with also optional arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614915/passing-optional-arguments-to-a-command-with-also-optional-arguments)
- [Empty optional argument or Not giving optional argument at all?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475998/empty-optional-argument-or-not-giving-optional-argument-at-all)
- [xparse: forward empty optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484292/xparse-forward-empty-optional-argument)
- [Pass 3 optional arguments in newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/613936/pass-3-optional-arguments-in-newcommand)

**Non-stackoverflow/stackexchange links:**

- https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands?
- [TeXFAQ: *More than one optional argument*](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-twooptarg#:%7E:text=LaTeX%20allows%20commands%20with%20a,have%20an%20argument%20of%20Default%20.)
- [Optional Arguments in LaTeX Macros](https://edunham.net/2015/03/30/optional_arguments_in_latex_macros.html)

**Using if conditional in latex:**

- https://riptutorial.com/latex/example/28656/if-statements
- [LaTeX \if condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286902/latex-if-condition)
- [You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/you-cant-use-macro-parameter-character-in-restricted-horizontal-mode)

References to use `\mbox` with `\cite` or `\parencite` inside `\newcommand` for highlighting.

**Highlighting text in Latex:**

- [YouTube Video: *How to highlight citations in LaTeX*](https://youtu.be/uqS5kbNdaew)
- [Problems with \ref when using soul for highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23307/problems-with-ref-when-using-soul-for-highlighting)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391698/how-to-highlight-references-numbers-and-citations-in-overleaf
- [How to highlight citations in a revised manuscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335992/how-to-highlight-citations-in-a-revised-manuscript)
- https://texblog.org/2015/05/20/using-colors-in-a-latex-document/amp/

Comment: Probably alternative title (for searching): "How can I propagate the empty argument to another command"?

Comment: Duplicate of [macros - Can you pass no optional argument to a command inside a command? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539940/can-you-pass-no-optional-argument-to-a-command-inside-a-command) though. Although this one has (in my opinion && vote count) better answer close vote the other way is preferable.

Comment: [macros - How to pass optional arguments to command? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353727/how-to-pass-optional-arguments-to-command) is a special case where passing empty to the inner command is harmless.

Comment: There's also [macros - Keeping default optional argument when adding to command - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579105/keeping-default-optional-argument-when-adding-to-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\NewDocumentCommand`.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\hlc}{O{yellow}m}{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\hlcite}{oom}{%
  \hlc[green]{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% no optional argument
      \parencite{#3}%
    }{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}{% just one optional argument
        \parencite[#1]{#3}%
      }{% both optional arguments
        \parencite[#1][#2]{#3}%
      }%
    }%
  }% end of \hlc
}
```

Note that you don't want a space between `\sethlcolor{#1}` ad `\hl{#2}`.

Comment: Thank you. So, I would need to add `\usepackage{xparse}` for using `\NewDocumentCommand`, right?

Comment: @CypherX If you have LaTeX released before 2020-10-01

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain, what happens if you leave space between `\sethlcolor{#1}` and `\hl{#2}`?

Comment: @CypherX Then you get a space in the output, what else? (occasionally that's *actually* what you want, but it's very rare.) Further reading: [symbols - What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @egreg Thank you. So, the `%` is the LaTeX equivalent of `-` used in Jinja2.

Comment: @CypherX I have no idea what Jinja2 is. The `%` is meant to avoid TeX insert a space by converting the endline.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?  Using `\newcommand`, one has to use at least two commands sequentially, if one wishes to absorb two optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\A[1][0]{\def\Atmp{0#1}\Ahelp}
\newcommand\Ahelp[2][0]{\expandafter\Axhelp\expandafter{\Atmp}{0#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\Axhelp[3]{\the\numexpr#1 + #2 + #3\relax}
\newcommand\B[1][0]{\def\Btmp{0#1}\Bhelp}
\newcommand\Bhelp[2][0]{\expandafter\Bxhelp\expandafter{\Btmp}{0#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\Bxhelp[3]{\the\numexpr#1 + \Axhelp{#2}{#3}{#1}\relax}
\begin{document}

\B{9}

\B[1][]{9}

\B[][3]{9}

\B[1][3]{9}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\B` command could be implemented more simply with

```
\NewDocumentCommand\B{ O{0} O{0} m }{\the\numexpr#1 + \Axhelp{0#2}{#3}{0#1}\relax}
```

However, the same is not true of `\A` because `\Ahelp` in the present case is expandable, whereas `\A` defined via `\NewDocumentCommand` is not.

Comment: Thank you. But, what I need more generally is way to pass `empty` arguments (not just zero). Basically what I need is this: `\newcommand{\hlcite}[3]{\hlc[green]{\mbox{\parencite[#2][#3]{#1}}}}`, where `\newcommand{\hlc}[2][yellow]{\sethlcolor{#1} \hl{#2}}` defines `\hlc`.

Comment: @steven-b-segletes : Since, your answer does what I asked initially, I voted it up. But it would be nice, if you could kindly help me with the actual problem of interest, I posted in the question later. Thank you.

Comment: @CypherX To allow true blank arguments (which do not work in the context of the `\numexpr` example originally specified), you need to do two things to my code: remove the `[0]` optional argument defaults and replace them with `[]`; and in `\A`, `\Ahelp`, etc, change the `0#1` to simply `#1`.

Comment: @steven-b-segletes : Thank you.