# Is there an empty value for the counter in `\newtheorem{xxxx}{xxxx}[empty]`?

Tags: amsthm, optional-arguments

I'm trying to set an optional counter in the `\newtheorem` command based on some input given to a `.sty` file. Something like

```
\DeclareOption{empty}{
    \edef\counter{} 
}

\DeclareOption{section}{
    \edef\counter{\detokenize{section}} 
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[\counter]
\providecommand*{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}
```

The `amsthm` package accepts `section` or `chapter` in `\counter`. I, instead, would like to **not** set a counter by setting `\counter` to some specific value. I've tried `\empty`,`0` and `{}` as above.

Of course, I could use a bunch of if's for each `\newtheorem` and simply set `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}` when I don't want to associate any counter. I would like to avoid that painful option, however.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wrote, "The `amsthm` package accepts `section` or `chapter` in `\counter`." That's somewhat misleading, as *any* valid counter variable can be used for "`\counter`. Do please clarify what you mean by "trying to set an optional counter in the `\newtheorem` command based on some input given to a .sty file". E.g., why does it have to be a .sty file?

Comment: @Mico I would like to make package with two possible parameters, `section` and `empty` that sets `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]` or `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}` depending on the chosen input in the main document using it. The point is that I have a bunch of `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}` in an `.sty` file that I'm writing, so I wouldn't like to use a bunch of if's. I would like, then to known whether there's some valid counter in the `amsthm` package such that "`\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}["valid counter"]`= `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}`".

Comment: @Mico By the way, `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[]` seems to have the same effect of `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}`. Still, I don't know how to define a new command `\counter` such that `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[\counter]` has the same effect of `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[]`. So I would like to define something like "let `\counter` be the empty command".

Comment: Not tested!  You might try creating `\newcounter{xthm}` and then `\newtheorem{xdefn}{Definition}[xthm]` and assign an appropriate value to the `xthm` counter.  (May work, maybe not, but seems worth trying, since it's known that the `equation` counter can be used in this way.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the suggestion, but how do I set the value of `xthm` to something empty? If I just define `\newcounter{xthm}` and set `\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[xthm]` inside the sty file, I get "Definition 0.1 "from `\begin{definition}`  inside the main tex document, whereas I would like "Definition 1" instead. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the value of the `xthm` counter really have to be "empty" (or "undefined")? Would it suffice for the *value* of this counter to be equal to `0` in order for the typeset *representation* of the `definition` counter to be "1" instead of "0.1"? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Do you mean `\setcounter{xthm}{0}` in the sty file? If so, in the main tex file `begin{definition}` appears later as "Definition 0.1". The 0 in 0.1 from `xthm`. I want to erase that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood the question correctly, but it seems like you want [macros - How to pass optional empty arguments in a newcommand down to another command with optional empty arguments in LaTeX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641252/how-to-pass-optional-empty-arguments-in-a-newcommand-down-to-another-command-wit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should force users of your package to have the numbering of definitions independent on theorems and friends.

There is no reason why an author should be forced to a style such as

**Lemma 1**
**Theorem 1**
**Theorem 2**
**Definition 1**
**Lemma 2**
**Theorem 3**

(maybe with section prefix, but that's irrelevant) instead of the more common and friendly

**Lemma 1**
**Theorem 2**
**Theorem 3**
**Definition 4**
**Lemma 5**
**Theorem 6**

(again with a possible prefix). I hate reading such a cross reference as

> see chapter II, part II, paragraph VI

or

> chapter V, part III, paragraph II, 2, theorem 2

These are from an actual book, which uses “part” instead of section, “paragraph” for subsection and doesn't name subsubsections. There is no clue whatsoever in the page headers about how to find the referenced theorem.

In your proposed “empty” style, the reader will have no clue as to whether Lemma 2 precedes or follows Theorem 1.

Anyway, if you insist on it (maybe because of strict faculty regulations), the trick is to define your own facility.

```
\DeclareOption{empty}{\let\package@thmprefix=F}
\DeclareOption{section}{\let\package@thmprefix=T\def\package@thmlevel{section}}
\DeclareOption{chapter}{\let\package@thmprefix=T\def\package@thmlevel{chapter}}

\DeclareOption{empty}{\let\package@thmprefix=F}
\DeclareOption{section}{\let\package@thmprefix=T\def\package@thmlevel{section}}
\DeclareOption{chapter}{\let\package@thmprefix=T\def\package@thmlevel{chapter}}

\ExecuteOptions{empty}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{amsthm}

\def\package@newtheorem#1#2{%
  \if\package@thmprefix F%
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}%
  \else
    \newtheorem{#1}{#2}[\package@thmlevel]
  \fi
}

\package@newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\package@newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\package@newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
```

Here's the test file

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{package}
%\usepackage[section]{package}
%\usepackage[chapter]{package}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

\begin{lemma}
Text
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}

\section{Title}

\begin{definition}
Text
\end{definition}

\begin{lemma}
Text
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
Text
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

#### Output with the `empty` option (default)

[image]

#### Output with the `section` option

[image]

#### Output with the `chapter` option

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You probably hate French Bourbakists then :-) . I'm not very proficient in the TeX syntax, so maybe what follows is trivial. What's `\package@thmprefix`? Is it something already defined or you're defining it on the first line? Is that lack of space between `T` and `\def` in the second line ( `...=T\def\...`) really necessary? Also, is it standard to use `T` and `F` for true and false in TeX? I've been searching for the correct syntax for a while. By the way, where can I find a list of all the logical operators defined in TeX?

Comment: @user40276 Definitely, as far as cross-references are concerned. :-D The `\package@thmprefix` is a package command I'm defining (replace `package` with something distinctive for your package). A space would not be ignored in that context (although it would be harmless). The only important thing is that the letters used (here `T` and `F`) are different.